# Overriding display() method and Using super to call default contructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, overriding

So for my assignment I have to create a sub class that inherits everything from your base class (Shoes.Java).

Here is what I'm stuck on:

Create a default constructor for the subclass, that uses super to call the base class default constructor. [1 point]
It should set all attributes in the subclass as well as the super class to default values

Override the display() method to print out all the instance variable values from the base class, and also from the sub class. [1 point]

I've tried creating a default contructor that uses super to call the base default contructor but it doesn't work.

Also for the Override method; How do I get it to print out the values from the sub class?

Base Class

```
    public class Shoes {


    //Instance Variables
    private String brand;
    private int price;
    private double size; 


    //Parameterized Constructor
        public Shoes (String brand, int price, double size)
        {
            this.brand = brand;
            this.price = price;
            this.size = size;
        }


    // Assigns instance variables to default values
        public Shoes(){
            brand = "";
            price = 0;
            size = 0;
        }


    /**
     * The setBrand method stores a value in the brand field.
     * @param brand The value to store in Brand.
     */

    public void setBrand (String brand)
    {
        this.brand=brand;
    }

    /**
     * The setPrice method stores a value in the price field.
     * @param price the value to store in price
     */

    public void setPrice (int price)
    {
        this.price=price;
    }

    /**
     * The setSize method stores a value in the size field.
     * @param size the value to store in size
     */

    public void setSize (double size)
    {
        this.size=size;
    }

    /**
     * The getBrand method returns Shoes brand.
     * @return the value in the brand field
     */

    public String getBrand()
    {
        return brand;
    }

    /**
     * the getPrice method returns Shoes price.
     * @return the value in the price field
     */

    public int getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * the getSize method returns Shoes size
     * @return the value in the size field
     */

    public double getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    // Prints out the values of all instance variables of your object
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("The Shoes brand is: " + brand);
        System.out.println("The Shoes price is: " + price);
        System.out.println("The Shoes size is: " + size);

    }


}
```

Sub Class

```
    public class RunningShoes extends Shoes{


    private String color;

public void display() {
     super.display();
     }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    RunningShoes shoesA = new RunningShoes();
    shoesA.setBrand("Nike");
    shoesA.setPrice(90);
    shoesA.setSize(8);
    shoesA.setColor("Pink");
    shoesA.display();

    RunningShoes shoesB = new RunningShoes("Adidas", 60, 7, "Blue");
    shoesB.display();}

    public RunningShoes (String color){

        this.setColor(color);


    }

    public RunningShoes(String brand, int price, double size, String color){
        super(brand, price, size);

    }

    //Create a default constructor that uses super to call the base class default constructor.
    //Need help here super.Shoes wont work

    public RunningShoes() {
        super();

    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }


}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work." - what does it mean ?What are you expecting ?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to call the base class default contructor with a super.  public RunningShoes() {
        super.Shoes;

Answer (score 1):

Your subclass display() method calls super.display(), but it needs to also print the subclass color field, like this:

```
    public void display()
    {
        super.display();
        System.out.println("The Shoe color is: "+color);
    }
```

However, if you only do that, you will get a null for the color, because the subclass constructor *being used* does not SET the color. It should look like this:

```
    public RunningShoes(String brand, int price, double size, String color)
    {
        super(brand, price, size);
        this.color = color;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Note that if you inherit a class. The constructor of the child class is invoked and it invoke it's parent's no-arg constructor (if it's there) otherwise it will throw an compile time error. Either to solve this, make a parent class no-arg constructor or if you want to call the parent class explicitly defined constructor, use `super(args,args,args);` in the constructor of child class. `Make sure it is at top of statements in child constructor.`

```
Refer to Constructor Chaining for more information.
```

## happyCoding